# Unable retain select option value after submit in django

Tags: django

I'm  trying to retain select option value after submit in django but unable to do. When I submit the button the select box disappeared.

Any suggestions?

> forms.py

```
class WardForm(forms.Form):
    ward_no = forms.ChoiceField(choices=[(x, x) for x in ['All', '1', '2', '3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','11','12','13','14','15']])
```

> Views.py

```
def post(request, template_name='report.html'):   
     if request.method == 'POST':       
        form=WardForm(request.POST)  

        return render(request, template_name,  {'form': form})
```

> reports.html

```
   {{ form.as_p}}
```

Comment: You say the select box disappeared - has the whole page gone blank, or can you still see other elements e.g. the submit button? Are there any errors in the console?

Comment: Actually , in my html page I tried to display the dynamic data in chart by selecting   option from multiple selectboxes. I used Forms API for slecting ward_no and I used manual select box for other select boxes. I am able to display chart as per the option selected. Except the  select box for ward_no everything displayed after form submission.

Comment: I can show you . Please help me.

Comment: OK, could you post the whole of your template and any other view code?

Comment: My views.py is https://dpaste.de/O8gM.

Comment: My template is https://dpaste.de/8g7U